# yarn workspaces monorepo with vite, react, tailwind - VS Code fails to resolve packages

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

I have created a monorepo using `yarn@3` workspaces.

My root `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "hello-yarn-workspaces",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.1.1",
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^16.0.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^16.0.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "husky install",
    "prepublishOnly": "pinst --disable",
    "postpublish": "pinst --enable"
  }
}
```

The `package.json` in `apps/ui`:

```json
{
  "name": "ui",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.1.1",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.4.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.1.3",
    "autoprefixer": "latest",
    "postcss": "latest",
    "tailwindcss": "latest",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "vite": "^2.7.10"
  }
}
```

I have created a component inside my `apps/ui/src` folder and when I run `yarn workspace ui run dev`, the app can be started in the browser.

However, when opening my monorepo in VS Code, it fails to resolve npm packages in `import` statements:

```js
// Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
import React, { ReactElement, useState } from 'react'
```

The same happens for the `vite.config.ts` in `apps/ui`

```js
// Cannot find module 'vite' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
// Cannot find module '@vitejs/plugin-react' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
```

When opening the monorepo in WebStorm, everything is ok.

The repro repository can be found [here](https://github.com/AlexZeitler/hello-yarn-workspaces).

**Update**: It looks like it is related to the `PnP` mechanism. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65328123/how-to-configure-vscode-to-run-yarn-2-with-pnp-powered-typescript) and setting `nodeLinker: node-modules` in `.yarnrc.yml` followed by `yarn install` fixed it.

However, the ansers for this question didn't work for me.

I get this error in VS Code after running `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`:

```
The path /Users/alexzeitler/src/hello-yarn-workspaces/.yarn/sdks/typescript/lib/tsserver.js doesn't point to a valid tsserver install. Falling back to bundled TypeScript version.
```

The files in `.yarn/sdks/typescript/lib` actually don't exist but I have a file `integrations.yml` in `.yarn/sdks`:

```yaml
# This file is automatically generated by @yarnpkg/sdks.
# Manual changes might be lost!

integrations:
  - vscode
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the missing pieces have been due to the [PnP configuration](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp):

```sh
yarn add --dev typescript ts-node prettier
yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode
```

Add a minimal `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["ESNext"],

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    /* Advanced Options */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Then install [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=arcanis.vscode-zipfs) VS Code extension followed by these steps:

- Press ctrl+shift+p in a TypeScript file
- Choose "Select TypeScript Version"
- Pick "Use Workspace Version"

More details can be found in the [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks).